# Netlogo: How to plot degree of nodes vs. average "reward" of turtles with that degree?

Tags: netlogo

I am building a model that tries to simulate a network-based market. In this model the turtles/nodes get a reward called *points*, which is a turtles-own variable.

I am now trying to plot a graph of the degree of the nodes against the average number of points that nodes with a given degree have. I have attempted to do this by creating a plot from the interface tab but I cannot manage to make this work.

Here are images of the windows of the plot settings.

[image]

[image]

Anybody know how can I make this work?

Also, I keep getting these "Runtime error: Can't find the maximum of an empty list" in all the plots/histograms I create. It is not a big deal at the moment as they seem to work fine, however if you know why these appear please let me know!

Thanks beforehand,

Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity and to avoid overloading your plot setup, I like to use `to-report` procedures for things like this. As a quick example try this setup:

turtles-own [ points degree ]

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 50 [
    set degree 5 + random 5    
    set points random 10
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ] 
  reset-ticks
end
```

Make a `to-report` each for a list of existing degrees, the average points of turtles that have each degree, and the maximum of those average point values:

```
to-report degrees-list 
  report sort remove-duplicates [degree] of turtles 
end

to-report avg-points-list
  let avg-list map [ i ->
    mean [points] of turtles with [ degree = i ]
  ] degrees-list
  report avg-list
end

to-report max-avg
  report precision ( max avg-points-list + 1 ) 2
end
```

In this example, `degrees-list` reports `[ 1 2 3 4 5 ]`, `avg-points-list` reports something like `[6.5 3.9285714285714284 6 3.75 4.2]`, and `max-avg` reports something like `7.5`- note that of course the exact values will vary since the setup is random.

Now, you can set up your plot window:

[image: Plot setup details]

The actual plotting is handled by the `foreach` primitive in the `plot pen`, which uses `plotxy` to plot the point value in `avg-points-list` against the corresponding value in `degrees-list`. Should give a plot that looks something like:

[image: Example plot]

Hope that's sort of what you're after!